# Setting up Citrix Netscaler ADC with VMware Workstation - Cannot access via web browser

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware, citrix

I'm new to this...

I try to explore the Citrix Netscaler ADC as part of the client's requirement to have load balancing for their new portal.

currently I have setting up an instance of Citrix Netscaler ADC via VMware Workstation.
[image]

As referring to:
http://www.robinhobo.com/configure-citrix-netscaler-10-5-including-gateway-citrix-storefront-2-5-2/

> After rebooting the NetScaler, open a browser and browse to the NSIP
>   address (management interface IP address) you entered in the previous
>   step. Login with User Name; nsroot and Password; nsroot

However, **my issue is that I can't even access the IP address I have configured (let's say 192.168.1.145) in the Netscaler via a browser.**

I can't get this screen from web browser. It seems that I can't ping to 192.168.1.145
[image]

What did I miss out here? do I need to change setting for the Network Adapters for the VM?

And I did try another approach by installing a **VMware ESXi** and deployed the **OVF template for Citrix Netscaler ADC**. Same issue happened as I can't access to the dedicated IP of 192.168.1.145.

[image]

Any idea to resolve this? Tks

Answer (score 0):

I managed to resolve the issue and get the console up by by changing NetScaler's IP Address from 192.168.1.145 to 192.168.65.145[image]